# Should I add a layer to keep object always valid and immutable?

Tags: c++, validation, immutability

I am developing COM. A factory need to be initialized first by providing a ID. I can not pass arguments to IFactory instance via CoCreateInstance. So IFactory may need add a `init` method to be called then. (as approach 2)

I don't want to require client to call `init` explicitly (they may forget). So that I add a layer named `IEntryPoint`. This ensures `GetFactory` will return a verified `IFactory` without called `init` first. Then the `IFactory` instance will not have the state denoted it is valid or invalid. All its methods can be const. (as approach 1)

Is it over encapsulated if `IEntryPoint` only has `GetFactory` method?

Approach 1: 
`IEntryPoint::GetFactory` ensures `IFactory` instance is valid if `S_OK` is returned.

```
interface IEntryPoint
{
    HRESULT GetFactory(size_t id, IFactory** ppFactory) const;
};


interface IFactory
{
    HRESULT GetInstance(size_t id, IInstance** ppInstance) const;
};


interface IInstance
{
    HRESULT Getter1() const;
    HRESULT Getter2() const;
    HRESULT Getter3() const;
};
```

vs

Approach 2: 
`IFactory` instance requires client to call `init` first.

```
interface IFactory
{
    HRESULT Init(size_t id);
    HRESULT GetInstance(size_t id, IInstance** ppInstance) const;
};


interface IInstance
{
    HRESULT Getter1() const;
    HRESULT Getter2() const;
    HRESULT Getter3() const;
};
```

Comment: What does `Init` do ? Is there no way to get rid of it and include its work in the constructor of a `IFactory`'s implementation ?

Comment: IFactory requires client to provide ID to start the init job. CoCreateInstance looks not allow me to pass argument when I create IFactory instance.

Answer (score 5):

Both solutions seem acceptable to me.

Your first solution is essentially a "factory factory", which might be perceived as unnecessary abstraction, but you are right that it firmly imposes the required workflow upon the user. This is a "pit of success" approach, where the *obvious* thing to do and the *right* thing to do are the same.

You are right that your second solution gives the client an opportunity to write a bug, an opportunity they will take!  But we can also assume that people writing COM clients are pretty smart and familiar with coclasses that need initialization.  I have written stateful COM objects with complex workflow requirements (multiple kinds of initialization and shutdown); the key to getting clients to write the code correctly was to be brutal about detecting client bugs and returning really, really harsh HRESULTS. My personal favourite was E_UNEXPECTED, which gave the error message "Catastrophic failure".

If you decide to go with your second option you should write code that detects invalid workflows -- calling `Init()` zero times, calling `Init()` two times, and so on -- and makes the factory object *completely unusable* any time that the contract is violated. Do not be lenient; that breeds bugs and undefined behaviour. If you have a workflow requirement then make that workflow as simple as possible, clearly document it, and force your clients to debug their code when they get it wrong.

A third pattern that I like is to modify your `Init` method so that instead of taking the ID it needs, instead it takes an object of type `IFactoryClient` that has a method `GetFactoryId` that returns an ID.  The caller is then required to supply a valid implementation of this interface. The factory then decides when to call the client to fetch its ID when it needs to. This technique is added overhead for the client, but it gives you a nice extension point for the future. Future versions of the factory can `QueryInterface` or `QueryService` the client to start a conversation between the client and the service about the level of services they expect from each other.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to required client to call init explicitly (they may forget)

As you said, approach 2 induces a temporal coupling which is really error-prone (user can forget to call `Init` and let a factory in an undefined state).

Obsviously, the best way to resolve this problem would be to provide the ID when constructing a implementation of `IFactory`. But since you're using COM and you can't pass arguments to the constructor, adding this layer (`IEntryPoint`) is the best way to limit this temporal coupling by encapsulating it and making it explicit in `IEntryPoints`'s implementation(s).